# How to raise a column in pandas DataFrame to consecutive powers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pow

Is there a pythonic way to raise a column in DataFrame (`xRaw`) to consecutive powers? Is there something like

```
xRaw[:,k] = xRaw.pow(k) for k in range(1,6)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
for i in range(6):
    xRaw["power: "+str(i)] = xRaw[column_to_be_raised] ** i
```

This is will generate a new column that takes its base from the column you want to raise for each exponent in the given range.

Answer (score 10):

This is a Vandermonde matrix, which numpy has a built-in function for [`np.vander`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html)

If you have

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Then

```
np.vander(s, 6)
```

```
array([[   1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [   1,    2,    4,    8,   16,   32],
       [   1,    3,    9,   27,   81,  243],
       [   1,    4,   16,   64,  256, 1024],
       [   1,    5,   25,  125,  625, 3125]])
```

To add back to a `df`, you can use `concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(vander)], axis=1)
```

Comment: How does this raise a row of an existing dataframe to various powers?

Answer (score 5):

Numpy broadcast

```
s.values**np.arange(6)[:,None]
Out[70]: 
array([[   1,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [   2,    4,    8,   16,   32],
       [   3,    9,   27,   81,  243],
       [   4,   16,   64,  256, 1024],
       [   5,   25,  125,  625, 3125]], dtype=int64)
```

Assign it back

```
s= pd.concat([s, pd.DataFrame(s.values**np.arange(6)[:,None],index=s.index)], axis=1)
```